# Connecting Arduino to PC without powering it

Tags: arduino

I'm doing a project with solar cell which is connected to battery. This battery should power the Arduino (some sensors are attached to it). At the same time, I need to keep the Arduino connected to my PC to finish my code depending on the values coming from sensors. The problem I'm facing is that the Arduino is taking power from the PC, and I don't want it to do so.

I know that the cable is for power and data, so I searched for a data-only cable, but it is not available in my region. Is there is any way to disable the power coming from PC?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no programming solution to this problem (it's hardware).

Comment: Agreed, it's hard to turn the question into a "do it in your sketch" hint ;)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "data only" usb cable.

I assume you are talking about an Uno or Mega 2560 with an USB plug and an ATmega16U2 handling the USB connection.

If battery power is available at Vin or the barrel jack, it will be used to power the Arduino.

Check https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560 or the corresponding Uno page and see the linked schematic PDF. I wouldn't break the polyfuse or apply other hacks.

If you want to inhibit your sketch from running while the battery is low but USB connected (why?), you could

- pull RESET to LOW
- check battery voltage via analogRead and act accordingly in the sketch.